# How to add HTML5 support to Chromium?

Tags: html5-video, chromium

I would like to know how to add HTML5 video support into a chromium build, by default chromium dose not play them.

Comment: Are you referring to adding support for mp4 videos in your own Chromium fork?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chromium, by default doesn't support playing those file formats. You will have to add support for those codecs when compiling Chromium. Chromium uses [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) build system, you should pass the below arguments or use this command

```
gn args out/YourBuildFolder
```

to open `args.gn` file in a text editor and paste and save it:

```
ffmpeg_branding = "Chrome"

proprietary_codecs = true
```

before compiling Chromium. Now compile your Chromium fork:

```
ninja -C out/YourBuildFolder chrome
```